# Linearity of partial trace

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, linear-algebra, trace

In *Quantum Processes Systems, and Information* by Schumacher and Westmoreland we are given this property of the partial trace

$$ Tr_R G^{RQ} = Tr_R \left( |\alpha^R,\phi^Q \rangle\langle\beta^R,\psi^Q| \right) =\\
=Tr_R \left(|\alpha^R \rangle \langle \beta^R|\otimes|\phi^Q\rangle\langle \psi^Q| \right)=\\
=\langle\beta^R|\alpha^R\rangle |\phi^Q\rangle\langle\psi^Q|.
$$

Can the partial trace still be found if $G^{RQ}$ can't be expressed as a tensor product of two operators? If we can instead express it as a sum of tensor products and do this:

$$ Tr_R G^{RQ} = Tr_R \left( |\alpha^R,\phi^Q \rangle\langle\beta^R,\psi^Q| + |\kappa^R,\zeta^Q \rangle\langle\lambda^R,\xi^Q|\right) =\\
=Tr_R \left(|\alpha^R \rangle \langle \beta^R|\otimes|\phi^Q\rangle\langle \psi^Q| + |\kappa^R \rangle \langle \lambda^R|\otimes|\zeta^Q\rangle\langle \xi^Q|\right)=\\
=\langle\beta^R|\alpha^R\rangle |\phi^Q\rangle\langle\psi^Q| + \langle\lambda^R|\kappa^R\rangle |\zeta^Q\rangle\langle\xi^Q| ?
$$

If it has this linearity property, how to prove it? What is the physical interpretation of there not being a tensor product that gives $G^{RQ}$. And if we can find a sum of tensor products then what's so special about them that makes this linearity true?

I didn't want to post it on math exchange because I'd probably not understand an answer written by a mathematician and I am also interested in the physical interpretation of what is happening here.

Comment: Yes, this holds, basically by definition/construction, cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714080/how-to-derive-the-reduced-density-matrix-in-a-mathematically-precise-and-correct) related question. There, the partial trace of a density matrix is defined (but this can be extended to more general operators).