# Inner product in a composite Hilbert space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, density-operator, trace

Take the two Hilbert spaces $ H_1 = H_2 = C^2$

The basis of $H_1$ is : $ \{ | 1 : + \rangle , |1 : - \rangle \}    $
and for $H_2$ :  $ \{ | 2 : + \rangle , |2 : - \rangle \}    $

Forming the composite Hilbert space:
$$ H = H_1 \otimes H_2 $$

We get the base of $H$ :  $ \{ | 1 : + \rangle \otimes | 2 : + \rangle  , | 1 : + \rangle \otimes | 2 : - \rangle , |  1 : - \rangle \otimes | 2 : - \rangle, | 1 : - \rangle \otimes | 2 : + \rangle \}    $. Written more simply as $$ \{| + + \rangle , | + - \rangle , | - - \rangle , |- + \rangle \} $$

Let the composite system be in a ket $$ | \Psi \rangle = \dfrac{ |+ - \rangle - | - + \rangle}{\sqrt{2}} $$

I wish to calculate the partial trace of the density operator with respect to $H_2$

$$ \rho_1 = tr_2 \rho = tr_2 | \Psi \rangle \langle \Psi| = \langle 2 : + | \Psi \rangle \langle \Psi | 2 : + \rangle  + \langle 2 : - | \Psi \rangle \langle \Psi | 2 : - \rangle  $$

I cannot get past this step , since I don't know what:
$$\langle 2: + |  + - \rangle   ?$$

Is it just $ \langle 2: + | 2: - \rangle = 0 $  ?

I know that for a vector space that is the tensor product of two other vector spaces
the scalar product is :

$$ (\langle 1:n' |\otimes \langle 2: p' |)| (|1 : n \rangle \otimes |2:p \rangle) = \ \langle 1:n'| 1 : n \rangle  \times \langle 2: p' | 2:p \rangle  $$

What is then :

$$ \langle 2: p' | (|1 : n \rangle \otimes |2:p \rangle) ? $$

Comment: This is the usual abuse of notation regarding the partial trace, I think. Have a look [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714080/how-to-derive-the-reduced-density-matrix-in-a-mathematically-precise-and-correct/714091#714091), for example.

Comment: ah ok , so  $ \langle 2 : + | + - \rangle$ is really  $( I_{d1} \otimes  \langle 2 : + | ) |+ - \rangle $. So $( I_{d1}+ \langle  +| ) |+ - \rangle   = |1 : +\rangle  ( \langle 2:+ | 2: - \rangle   ) $

Comment: Sorry, it is hard for me to read this notation (especially in a comment).

Comment: $$ \left(\mathbb I_A \otimes \langle \psi| \right) (|\varphi\rangle \otimes|\phi\rangle) = |\varphi\rangle \langle \psi|\phi \rangle \quad $$ is what I meant to say

Comment: Yes, indeed. As I've explained in the linked answer, the notation you encountered (I suppose), is a common abuse of notation (cf. eq. 4 there).

Answer (score 1):

Using your notation, you already pointed out that ${|2:+⟩,|2:−⟩}$ form a basis in $_2$, so $⟨2:+|2:−⟩$ is definitely zero.

Second, you also observed the rule by which the inner product and tensor product interchange, i.e.

$(⟨1:′|⊗⟨2:′|)|(|1:⟩⊗|2:⟩)= ⟨1:′|1:⟩⊗⟨2:′|2:⟩
                            =⟨1:′|1:⟩⟨2:′|2:⟩$,

where in the last equality the tensor product transforms into scalar product since $⟨1:′|1:⟩$ and $⟨2:′|2:⟩$ are just numbers.

Exactly the same rule applies to your last equation, the only difference is that there you have an inner product only between vectors of $_2$, while the vector of $_1$ remains unchanged

$⟨2:′|(|1:⟩⊗|2:⟩)=|1:⟩⊗⟨2:′|2:⟩=|1:⟩⟨2:′|2:⟩$.

This is exactly what you should obtain, namely, the second system is traced out by projecting it on $|2:⟩$, while the first system remains untouched, which is given by the vector $|1:⟩$.

Comment: Consider to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Noted, thanks. @Tobias Fünke