# Trace of a density matrix that is acted upon by a separable linear operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator, trace

If we let $\hat{\rho}$ be the density matrix of a Bell state. I have seen that calculating the trace,

$$
Tr(\hat{A} \otimes \hat{I} \hat{\rho}) = Tr_{\mathcal{H}_A}(\hat{A}\hat{\rho}_{\mathcal{H}_A})
$$

Where $Tr_{\mathcal{H}_A}$ is the partial trace in the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_A$ and $\hat{\rho}_{\mathcal{H}_A}$ is the reduced density matrix $\hat{\rho}_{\mathcal{H}_A} = Tr_{\mathcal{H}_B}(\hat{\rho})$.

Would someone please be able to provide some clarity on why this is true, and if there is a more general formula for when we act on $\hat{\rho}$ with an arbitrary linear operator $\hat{A}\otimes\hat{B}$?

Comment: That holds by definition, see e.g. [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714080/how-to-derive-the-reduced-density-matrix-in-a-mathematically-precise-and-correct).